The Curvature of Electric Field Lines
I have been practicing many questions regarding electrical field lines. However, I can't seem to understand when electrical field lines remain straight and when they start to curve. Does it depend on the shape of the charged object? Or does it have other factors which cause it to curve?

In electrostatics, the rule is that field lines originate on positive charges and end on negative charges. This is a description in English of the Gauss Law. What impacts on whether the lines stay straight or curve is the complete distribution of charges. The field lines will then curve as necessary for them to leave at positive charges and end at negative charges. Depending on this particular arrangement of charges a given field line might or not need to curve. In general, however, the field lines will indeed be curved, and only a few exceptions with exceptional symmetry will remain straight.
In short, yes, it depends on the shape of the charged object (to be more precise, on the shapes of all charged objects). Highly symmetrical field lines might remain straight, but most of them will curve in order to satisfy the rule that lines start at positive charges and end at negative charges.
I should add that in electrodynamics the situation is more complicated because the electromagnetic field is not entirely determined by the distribution of charges and currents. Hence, in that more general case, only knowing the shape of the charged object is not enough to determine the field lines: you also need information on the overall state of the electromagnetic field (this can be given in the form of an initial condition).
I should also add that we are rarely interested in the particular curvature of the field lines.

Field lines can be used as a visual aid and Faraday assigned some properties to magnetic field lines at first.
Electric field lines,

start on a positive charge and end on a negative charge,
are in a state of tension,
repel each other, and
never intersect each other.

Furthermore, the electric field is strong when the lines are close together, and weak when the field lines are further apart from one another.
Using these "properties", attraction (opposite sign charges), and repulsion (same sign charges) could be "explained".
Thus, your curved electric field lines can be "explained" by the lines being pushed away from a region where there are lots of lines into regions were there are fewer lines.
Think of the field between two opposite sign charges.
Also the impossibility of there being no fringe field outside a parallel plate capacitor.
Nowadays all of this can be shown mathematically using the laws of electromagnetism but sometimes, a picture is worth a thousand words.

An electric field line is a line whose direction at every point along it is the direction of the (resultant) electric field at that point.
So the field lines from a single positive point charge (with other charges far away) are straight lines radiating out from the charge.
Suppose now that we have equal and opposite point charges (+Q and –Q) some distance, $l$, apart. At points much closer than $l$ to +Q or –Q the field will be radially outward from +Q or inward to –Q. This is because the field due to the more remote charge will be negligible compared to that from the nearby charge. So the field lines, as they come out from $+Q$ and as they return to $–Q$ are almost straight. But (except for the one line going directly from $+Q$ to $–Q$) the lines must bend when the fields due to the two charges are of comparable magnitude. For example consider the direction of the resultant field (the vector sum of the fields due to the individual charges) at any non-central point, P, along the perpendicular bisector of the line joining the charges. You should have found that it is parallel to the line joining the charges. The field line starting on $+Q$ and passing through P on its way to $–Q$ can't be straight all the way!
So even with almost the simplest configuration of charges the electric field lines show the transition from straight to curved – and this is simply as a result of the vector addition of field strengths due to the individual charges. The same principle can be used to find the shapes of field lines due to more complicated charge configurations.
